# Elasticsearch find the total number of grandchildren

Tags: elasticsearch, join

I am trying to set up a mapping using JOIN in Elasticsearch for my data, which have the relationship: company is in an one-to-many relationship with group, and group is in an one-to-many relationship with user.

Here is my mapping:

```
PUT /company
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1, "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "mapping.single_type": true
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "company": { "type": "text" },
        "group": { "type": "text" },
        "user": { "type": "text" },
        "company_relations": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "company": "group",
            "group": "user"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After I have created the mapping and populated the index. How do I query for how many users does a specific company have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, change your mapping to the below. The reason is you cannot apply and perform aggregation queries on the `text` field. You would need `keyword` field for that.

Also I would not advise you to enable `fielddata: true` as it may have impact on the performance once your index size increases plus it makes no sense. More on this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#before-enabling-fielddata)

```
{ 
   "settings":{ 
      "number_of_shards":1,
      "number_of_replicas":0,
      "mapping.single_type":true
   },
   "mappings":{ 
      "doc":{ 
         "properties":{ 
            "company":{ 
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{ 
                  "keyword":{ 
                     "type":"keyword"
                  }
               }
            },
            "group":{ 
               "type":"text"
            },
            "user":{ 
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{ 
                  "keyword":{ 
                     "type":"keyword"
                  }
               }
            },
            "company_relations":{ 
               "type":"join",
               "relations":{ 
                  "company":"group",
                  "group":"user"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Post that ingest your document as below (For the sake of simplicity, I've just used concerned fields and not made use of relations)

### Sample Docs:

```
POST company/doc/1
{
  "company": "daimler",
  "group": "abc",
  "user": "austin"
}

POST company/doc/2
{
  "company": "daimler",
  "group": "abc",
  "user": "matt"
}
```

Now your query could be as simple as below where I've used [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [Cardinality Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) to get what you are looking for:

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST company/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "company.keyword": "daimler"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "my_companies": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "company.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_users_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "user.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've used aggregation on `company.keyword` and `user.keyword` fields.

Below is how response appears

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_companies" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "daimler",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "my_users_count" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think I have a pretty good understanding of the query here; however, if you have other companies stored too, where do you specify that the company name is daimler so that only the total number of users from daimler are shown in the result?

Comment: I've updated my answer. For exact matches, you would need to use `Term Query` on `keyword` field. Do note that.

Comment: ES queries have like one aspect, which is plain simple query, which acts like what documents would you want to return and then another aspect would be aggregation queries which are used for aggregation purposes. Note that I've also specified `size:0` that is because I only want to view results of aggregation queries and not return the documents as response.

Answer (score 1):

```
Change your mapping to:

PUT /company
{

  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "company": { "type": "text"},
        "group": { "type": "text" },
        "user": { "type": "text","fielddata": true},
        "company_relations": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "company": "group",
            "group": "user"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then use this query:

```
GET company/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "company": "company name"
    }
  },"aggs": {
    "total_users": {
      "value_count": {
         "field": "user"
      }
    }
  }
}
```